# Eclipse complaining about web-app attributes

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

My web-app declaration in my web.xml is:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >
```

And eclipse complains about all 4 attributes, here is one Eclipse complaint:

```
Attribute "version" must be declared for element type "web-app"
```

Why is Eclipse complaining about these attributes?  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: When is it complaining?  Have you tried forcing it to revalidate?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Remove the DOCTYPE line, that is what the xsd is meant to replace. I had the same issue and only this had worked.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem. I tried a different schema location and it worked for me. Instead of

`xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"`

try using this

`xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd`

Also, set the version as `"3.0"`.

Answer (score 12):

Try to put in this way:

```
<web-app  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"   version="2.4" >
```

Eclipse validator is very strict with the order.

Comment: Yes, I see http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd so the version must be 2.4. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Didn't you forget this row in your xml file?:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

Your file should start like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
```

If it doesn't work clean and refresh your project.

Answer (score 4):

I changed the declaration from

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

to the following and it worked like charm. Now no errors shown in web.xml

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/index.html#7) oracle.com link to know what all were announced with Java EE 7 (assuming that is what we're working with). The link states

> All new schemas are in the http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/
>   namespace.

The namespace `java.sun` has not become `java.oracle`, instead it has been retained by [The Java Community Process (JCP)](https://www.jcp.org/). Hence all namespaces should point to xmlns.jcp.org, as is also pointed out by Java EE 7 docs.

Now, when we are deploying a web application (and hence the need to define a web.xml), first we have to know what we intend to do.

Say, we are working with Apache Tomcat V8. If we read the docs [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/), we get to know that it comes with Servlet 3.1 bundled. So, I would prefer an implementation of Servlet 3.1, just to stay up to date if not anything else.

Now all that being said, this is the declaration I would have

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

</web-app>
```

Hope this answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

All I have done is, replaced all the xsd and schema location declarations with the below one,

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
```

It started working fine.

reference:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/web_xml.htm#WBAPP502

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the DOCTYPE. And its works fine.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: For me removing the DOCTYPE fixed the error.  This will be at the top of your web.xml file - "<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >"