# Attributes in the web.xml's <web-app> don't work in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web.xml

I have a multi-module Maven project. It works fine in NetBeans. But not in Eclipse (EE Helios SR 1). In the web.xml file I have the following:

```
<web-app version="3.0" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
             metadata-complete="true">
```

I get 5 xml errors. Each one looks like that:

> Attribute "version" must be declared for element type "web-app"

And the `"version"` part is changed to `"xmlns:xsi"` and so on in the other errors. I tried to change Dynamic Web Module version to 3.0, but it didn't help.

When moving to Eclipse I did `mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0` in the war module and `mvn eclipse:eclipse` in the others. I also installed `m2e` and `m2e-wtp` plugins. So, I suppose the project should work fine with that.

Why can't Eclipse work with a project, that's working in another IDE? I also had to change `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` to `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>` on one of the JSP, which was a little strange too, because the old version of this uri worked in NetBeans.

Hope someone could clarify the reasons of its (unexpected for me) behavior and how this can be fixed.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't entirely address the concern. I had written an answer for another question. Please check that once. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37727445/2717158) is the link

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use 2.4 instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee">
```

Edited.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Too bad, same errors for each attribute with your code sample. Do you have any idea why this could happen?

Comment: See edited. Also once the file is saved, select `project ->clean` to re-validate and compile your project instances.

Comment: Great, it works now. Well, I still don't know how to run it normally (NetBeans is so much easier in some way), but that's another issue, and there are no errors, which is great, thanks. Still, if you could explain the reason it works differently in different IDEs, I'd be grateful.